# C program skips fgets

Tags: c, scanf

My program compiles ok but it when it calls the getinput() function it never prompts for input.

Edited to show more code, I added fflush but it still skips it for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main(){

    char mystring[] = "It's equal to it. ";
    int k = 32;
    int e;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    if(e == k){
        printf("\n\n%s\n",mystring);

    } else if(e < k){
        printf("\n\n%d\n",e);

    } else {


        getinput();
    }

    exit(0);

}

int getinput(){

    char gettext[64];

    printf("Enter text here: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(gettext, 64, stdin);
    printf("\n\nYou entered: %s\n\n",gettext);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Your title says it skips `fgets`, but your question is more about `printf`.

Comment: @WillBD Looks like that question is a different problem, because of mixing `scanf` and `fgets`.

Comment: Ah, a good point, I didn't see your comment (and therefore re-read the question) until after I put mine up, good catch.

Comment: @WillBD It turns out you were presciently correct. He's added more code to the question.

Comment: @Barmar yea but scanf is not used inside the getinput function so i don't see why that would matter.

Comment: It's used BEFORE the `getinput()` function. What matters is the state of the `stdin` stream when `getinput()` is called.

Answer (score 4):

after this line `scanf("%d",&e)` add a `getchar()` like this :

```
scanf("%d",&e);
getchar();
```

when you press `Enter` the newline character stays in the buffer so when `fgets` is called the newline is passed to it and it actes as if you pressed `Enter`

Comment: You've got the right idea about what's going on here. However, `getchar()` isn't a robust fix. I think there's a way to put some extra stuff in the `scanf()` format to make it "eat" the rest of the line, but I'm still working out the best way to do that. I'll post when I have more details...

Comment: Okay, here's what seems to work: `scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &e); assert('\n' == getchar());` The assert is optional of course (but the getchar() is not). I just wanted to be sure I was eating the newline, and not some other character by accident. The `%*[^\n]` that I added basically says "match everything that is not a newline" (`[^\n]` pattern) "but do not assign it to any variable" (that's what the `*` does).

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `fflush(stdout);` after your first printf.

`printf` will flush it for you, but only when it has a newline at the end (e.g. `printf("hi\n");`)

Comment: This is true, and OP should do this. However, it is not the cause of the bug he asked about.

Comment: It could be - it seems to him or her that the input is wrong, but he's judging that by the *output* ... hence my answer.